# What should I check to find out if a web developed in aspx is migrable to linux?

Tags: asp.net, linux, iis, migration

I've access to a Windows Server 2016. It has a IIS 10 that served a ASPX web application (corporate web and ERP).
I work with debian server and I wondering if will be possible migrate this web application to debian. I'm not very knowledgeable about .NET but I've read the possibility of using ASP Core or Mono, but depends what framework are used and others requierements that I don't know.

Do you recommend that I take any approach to find out if migration is viable?

Comment: You should assume none of them can go via Mono as there is no production support from any vendor I heard of. If you plan to migrate to ASP.NET Core, Microsoft does have migration guides and support services. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

`ASPX` web application is exclusively to `Asp.net` web form application, which is a Microsoft web framework. It is not a cross-platform framework, which means it cannot run in other platform. As you mentioned, `Asp.Net Core` is a cross-platform framework, a web application created by Asp.net Core can perfectly work in `Debian distribution`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/dependencies?pivots=os-linux&tabs=netcore31
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Accessing to web I can see aspx in the URL. With this facts, can I assum is not a cross-platamorf framework and impossible migrated (or extremly difficult to do)?

Comment: I think so, you can try to port your application to AspNet Core since AspNet Core web application works perfectly in other platform.

Comment: I haven't the source code to port to AspNet Core. I've only the applicatión running on Windows Server. I think my idea is not viable so